# Type Mismatch Swift JSON

Tags: ios, json, swift, api, type-mismatch

I think I created the structure correctly, but it gives error.

**typeMismatch(Swift.Array, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil))**

Model:

```
struct veriler : Codable {
    let success : Bool
    let result : [result]
    
}

struct result : Codable {
    let country : String
    let totalCases : String
    let newCases : String
    let totalDeaths : String
    let newDeaths : String
    let totalRecovered : String
    let activeCases : String
}
```

JSON data:

```
{
  "success": true,
  "result": [
    {
      "country": "China",
      "totalcases": "80,881",
      "newCases": "+21",
      "totaldeaths": "3,226",
      "newDeaths": "+13",
      "totalRecovered": "68,709",
      "activeCases": "8,946"
    },
    {
      "country": "Italy",
      "totalcases": "27,980",
      "newCases": "",
      "totaldeaths": "2,158",
      "newDeaths": "",
      "totalRecovered": "2,749",
      "activeCases": "23,073"
    },
    "..."
  ]
}
```

Decoding:

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        do {
            let country = try decoder.decode([result].self, from: data!)
          for i in 0..<country.count {
            print (country[i].country)
          }
        } catch {
          print(error)
        }
```

Comment: why not `veriler.self` instead of `[result].self`!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to modify your `result` struct by specifying custom `CodingKeys` (note the mismatch between `totalCases` in the model and `totalcases` in the JSON):

```
struct result: Codable {
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case country, newCases, newDeaths, totalRecovered, activeCases
        case totalCases = "totalcases"
        case totalDeaths = "totaldeaths"
    }
    
    let country: String
    let totalCases: String
    let newCases: String
    let totalDeaths: String
    let newDeaths: String
    let totalRecovered: String
    let activeCases: String
}
```

Then you need to decode `veriler.self` instead of `[result].self`:

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
do {
    let result = try decoder.decode(veriler.self, from: data!)
    let countries = result.result
    for i in 0 ..< countries.count {
        print(countries[i].country)
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Note: I recommend to follow Swift guidelines and name structs like `Result` or `Veriler` (only instances should be lowercase).

Comment: It's given this error.      keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "totalcases", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "result", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"totalcases\", intValue: nil) (\"totalcases\").", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: Did you try this code on the JSON from the question? Because in your question I can clearly see `totalcases`. Make sure you have the same fields in your actual JSON. If not just adapt the CodingKeys.

Comment: will it be helpful if I share the api website and all codes? Because response code is 200. So no problem from the website?

Comment: @E.YILDIRIM There's no need if you can confirm the JSON in your question is *the exact same* JSON you're trying to parse. Otherwise you can update the question with the actual JSON.

Comment: when I remove totalcases , its gives error with totaldeaths. Then remove totaldeaths, it works now. So there is a problem with these two

Comment: @E.YILDIRIM Then you posted the wrong JSON in the question. Try using my answer but without the `CodingKeys` enum and it should work.

Comment: It worked when I changed their names (totalCases , totalDeaths) . The sample names given by the site were wrong. So it is not originated from us. Thank you for all your help :)